# import issues in monorepo setting

Tags: python

I am struggling with import issues with Python. I am working in a mono repo setting, where other directories are not related to python. Following is the structure of the directory.

```
monorepo
    services
        app1
        app2
            __init__.py
            src
                __init__.py
            api
                __init__.py
                foo1.py
                foo2.py
        app3
```

I want to use the import structure of `from app2.api.foo1 import Foo1` in foo2.py script.

In both cases, it fails. I see the path to app2 in the sys.path but still python does not see this as a module.
To export the path: I tried.
`PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:$(realpath $(pwd))"` at terminal and
`sys.path.append(full_path_app2)` at console level. Still get the import error.

Any help on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python imports can be tricky.

- Python will look for importable modules inside the PythonPath (sys.path).
- Importable modules are subfolders of any location in the path which contain a `__init__.py` file.
- If you call a script file directly `python script.py` the directoy containing that file is added to the path automatically. If you use the module syntax `python -m mymodule` it will search the `PYTHONPATH` and execute the first module with the name `mymodule`.

In order to import app2, you need to add `monorepo/services` to the PythonPath. This should also allow you to directly import files in app2, i.e. `from app2 import xyz`.

If you are working with monorepos, you need to add all folders which may contain python modules to the path. I would recommend doing it using the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` instead of modifying `sys.path` programmatically.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I ended up using setup.py for my app and do `pip install -e .` and I guess there is no way around this when we have to import across folders.

Comment: I also default to using `pip install -e` nowadays, it is a lot easier than managing all the PYTHONPATHs manually in a monorepo setting.

Comment: Why do you recommend using PYTHONPATH instead of manipulating sys.path?

Comment: @jhexp if the code is shared, it will modify the path of a foreign system. path is even modified just by importing. it might not be what user intends. This can lead to mysterious errors and strange sideeffects if someone tries to import a function from your code. Rather you would provide instructions to modifying PYTHONPATH and let the user handle that for you. In any case basically it is good practice to separate Environment and Code. Code should expect everything to be readily available, not depend on any particular system layout. the environment should make everything available.